# Find an integral's limit, with constraints on the method of solving.

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

thanks for taking the time to read this question. I'm not going to lie, it's a part of my 30+ question homework, but I've just spent an entire week trying to solve it, and I only need a tiny bit of help, a nudge in the right direction. Here's the question:

Let $g(x) = \int_x^{x^2} \frac{1}{\ln t} dt $, for $x > 0$ and $x \neq 0 $.

$(1) t - \frac{t^2}2 \leqslant \ln(1+t) \leqslant t$

$(2) \frac{1}{t - \frac{t^2}2} = \frac{1}{t} + \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1 - \frac{t}{2}}$

Deduce from (1) and (2) that g(x) has a finite limit as $x\to1$. I've tried lots of things, including limited development using McLaurin's formula to express $e^x$ (Taylor expansion in 0), which worked, but the proof needs to use statements (1) and (2). I've also tried using Darboux sums and Riemann sums to no avail.

Comment: $g(x)$ has a finite limit, as $x$ approaches what?

Comment: Sorry, when I say "in 1" I actually mean as x approaches 1.

Comment: Ok, so $g(x) = \int_{x-1}^{x^2-1} \frac1{\ln(1+t)}\,dt$. What happens when you apply the hints?

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to find two ways to solve it, the first one using (1) and (2) and the second one using the MacLaurin series (I'll post the second one a bit later, when I'm done writing it down).

**Method 1**, using (1) and (2)

Let $t = 1 + u$. Then, $du = dt$. In that case, g becomes:

$$ g(x) = \int_{x-1}^{x^2-1} \frac{1}{\ln{(t+1)}}dt $$

From $(2)$, we can deduce the following:

$$ \frac{1}{t - \frac{t^2}{2}} \geqslant \frac{1}{\ln{t}} \geqslant \frac{1}{t}$$

$$ \int_{x-1}^{x^2-1} \frac{1}{t - \frac{t^2}{2}}dt \geqslant g(x) \geqslant \int_{x-1}^{x^2-1} \frac{1}{t}dt $$

Now, we apply $(3)$ and obtain:

$$ \int_{x-1}^{x^2-1} (\frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{2-t})dt \geqslant g(x) \geqslant \int_{x-1}^{x^2-1} \frac{1}{t}dt $$

$$ \int_{x-1}^{x^2-1} \frac{1}{t}dt - \int_{x-1}^{x^2-1}\frac{1}{2-t}dt \geqslant g(x) \geqslant \int_{x-1}^{x^2-1} \frac{1}{t}dt $$

$$ \ln{(\mid{x^2 - 1}\mid)} - \ln{(\mid{x - 1}\mid)} - \ln{(\mid{3 - x^2}\mid)} + \ln{(\mid{3 - x}\mid)} \geqslant g(x) \geqslant \ln{(\mid{x^2 - 1}\mid)} - \ln{(\mid{x - 1}\mid)} $$

$$ \ln{\mid \frac{(x+1)(3-x)}{3-x^2} \mid} \geqslant g(x) \geqslant \ln{\mid x+1 \mid} $$

Since the limits of both the leftmost member and the rightmost member are $ln{(2)}$ as x approaches 1, we can deduce that $\lim\limits_{x \to 1}{g(x)} = \ln{2}$.